# How can I access and queried object's id using Parse?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parse-platform, ionic-framework

I'm trying to get the id of a queried object, how can I do this?

My query:

```
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
query.equalTo("username", "user1"); 
query.find({
  success: function(item) {
        console.log(item) // This works
        console.log(item.id) // This is undefined
  }
});
```

My returned data resembles this in the console:

```
> f 
  > createdAt : "May 28"
  > _serverData:
    > username: "user1"
    > email: "user1@gmail.com"
  > id: "93jcdn19"
```

How can I access the id within my javascript code?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that returns an array, so you would do `console.log(item[0].id)`

To print out every object's id you would do something like

```
for (var index = 0; index < item.length; index++){
    console.log(item[index].id)
}
```

Comment: Would you how to do it for every item in the array, instead of just the first one?